# Using <AutoGenerateBindingRedirects> in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, dll, binding

I am new to Visual Studio, so please be patient.

I am working on a product that depends on a dll file that is  provided by a third party. We will call them OtherCompany.dll. We do not distribute this.

Our  product contains a dll file that is dependent on OtherCompany.dll. We will call it MyCompany.dll. When we build MyCompany.dll, we are currently building against version 1.0.0 of OtherCompany.dll.  However, we recently discovered that OtherCompany.dll changed its version to 2.0.0. There were no changes to existing functionality, only additions.

Some users purchased OtherCompany.dll version 2.0.0 and now our product breaks as version 1.0.0 is not in the GAC.  I understand this is a common issue, and I have been trying to discover a good solution.

I attempted to add  into my .csproj file for our MyCompany.dll and building against OtherCompany.dll version 1.0.0, and install it on a machine with OtherCompany.dll version 2.0.0.  It is still failing with the error

Could not load file or assembly 'OtherCompany, Version=1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=1234' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

I understood that   would allow MyCompany.dll to be version independent of OtherCompany.dll. What did I do wrong or misunderstand ?

I was able to get things to work by manually adding  into the products .config file, but this is cumbersome and I would like something that would continue to work, in case next week OtherCompany.dll releases version 3.0.0.

Comment: Have you tried to use [bindingRedirect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eftw1fys(v=vs.110).aspx) in your config file? Just specify that any version from 1.0.0 to 2.0.0 (or whatever) need to be redirected to use 2.0.0. And I don't know about autogenerated binding redirects.

Comment: Moreover, if your product depends on 'other product' with some specific version, why just not to stick to this version (provide with it in package) and update it only when you update your own.

Comment: Yes, binding redirect works.  We are not able to provide the 'other product' in our installation due to licensing restrictions.

Comment: Well, then, if you have an installer of your product, you can ask user about which version they have and update config during installation. But if they will update third-party library - it will fail again. I think you just need to solve license issue.

Comment: I don't disagree with you on the licensing issue, but that is up to legal, and not me.

Comment: There is no other solution. At least I don't know the others.

Comment: Moreover, what if in the next version of third party library will be some changes in API - automatic switch to this version will break your application.